# R language: Reading non-standard csv

Tags: r, csv

My csv file looks like this(if open in Excel):

```
1     "A long string describing following data"
2     id      name      sex
3     14      Jeff       M
4     17      Mary       F
...
1430  "Another long string describing following data"
1431  4729    John       M
1432  5870    Tina       F
...
```

I want read these data into R without those describing lines(there are many such lines, I can't do it manually), how can I do this?

I tried `read.csv` but it says:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
```

Comment: Do the names follow a pattern? Do they always start with a string rather than a numeric value? If so, you can easily read them into a `list` with the help of `readLines` and `grep`.

Comment: Perhaps using `comment.char="\""`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto I'm new to R so I don't quite follow your suggestion, would you please help me with an example? Actually it's long string not a single word, I think it's safe to assume numeric value won't appear at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment (but not read in as a `list`), save your file as a CSV. I'm assuming the first set of numbers are actually just row numbers of some form, and not part of the actual data.

```
x <- tempfile() ## We'll pretend this is your actual CSV file

cat("A long name describing following data",
"id      name      sex",
"14      Jeff       M",
"17      Mary       F",
"Another long name describing following data",
"4729    John       M",
"5870    Tina       F", sep = "\n", file = x)
```

You can search for all the lines that start with the character class `[a-zA-Z]` using `grep`. `grep` has an option to invert the results and to also show the value instead of the position. Both of these are useful for `read.table`:

```
read.table(text = grep("^[a-zA-Z]", readLines(x), 
                       value = TRUE, invert = TRUE), 
           header = FALSE)
#     V1   V2 V3
# 1   14 Jeff  M
# 2   17 Mary  F
# 3 4729 John  M
# 4 5870 Tina  F
```

The column `names` are easy to add in later.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `count.fields` to read only those lines with 4 items or exclude those lines with a specified number of items, e.g.,

```
# make a temporary test file
text <- '1     "A long name describing following data"
2     id      name      sex
3     14      Jeff       M
4     17      Mary       F
1430  "Another long name"
1431  4729    John       M
1432  5870    Tina       F'
temp.path <- tempfile()
write(text, temp.path)

# read data
read.table(text=readLines(temp.path)[count.fields(temp.path) == 4], header=TRUE)
#     X2   id name sex
# 1    3   14 Jeff   M
# 2    4   17 Mary   F
# 3 1431 4729 John   M
# 4 1432 5870 Tina   F

# remove tempfile
unlink(temp.path)
```

Comment: Interesting concept, but wouldn't work with lines like `1430  "Another long name"`, right?

Comment: Actually, it would in this case, because of the quotes.